# What is the difference between a HUD and a GUI in a game?

Tags: gui, terminology, hud

Does anyone know the difference between a graphical HUD (head-up display) and a GUI (graphical user interface) in a game? Is a HUD part of the GUI and just displaying information? That would mean that I can not technically interact with a HUD while I could with the GUI (e.g. clicking a button)? Or are both terms basically describing the same thing?

Note: I'm talking about these words while being ingame.

See the following example:

[image: overwatchguiorhud?]

What would be described as GUI in this image and what as HUD?

Comment: The answers have different assumptions about what a HUD is. DMGregory's answer assumes it is an informational static screen displayed over the game window. Bram assumes a HUD is a graphical non-interactive display. The definition needs to be included in the question.

Comment: This question is similar to asking what is the difference between a button and a GUI.

Comment: _Offtopic: This is the most creative username I have ever seen on this site._

Comment: I don't think this needs another answer, but i'd point out that the purpose of a HUD is to permit an individual to get the information they need without having to look away from what they need to focus on.  The term is more natural in its original setting (fighter planes) where a HUD let you see things without having to look at instrument panels, but I still feel that goal of not taking focus away from what matters is key for defining a HUD.

Comment: HUD equals GUI but GUI doesn't always equal HUD

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) on what a GUI is?

Comment: @jpmc26 , if u were referring to me I read both wikipages. HuD and GUI.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I'd argue that HUDs *are* graphical user interfaces: they're ways to present information back to the user graphically.

In contrast to what some other answers say, the term GUI doesn't require that every element be directly interactive - the label next to a control on a form is still part of the GUI, guiding the player in how to interact with the system, even if clicking the label itself doesn't accomplish anything.

What distinguishes HUD elements is the particular *way this information is displayed* to the user: "Heads-Up Display" was coined in contrast to a light or dial on a control panel, where the user would need to look down / away from the window and world in front of them to check on it. The defining feature of being "Heads-Up" is that the information is overlaid over the world, rather than in its own separate dashboard, and it often tracks with the user's camera or head rather than needing them to turn to a particular location to see it (particularly notable in VR games).

So for example, in this StarCraft screenshot, I would argue that the selection and health overlays on the units, and resource counters in the corner, all constitute HUD, being overlaid on the game world. The map, order buttons, and selection readouts in the chrome below would not be HUD because they exist outside the world viewport.

[image: Screenshot of Starcraft contrasting different types of GUI]

It's more common to see the term HUD applied in 1st person and 3rd person over-the-shoulder perspectives than to top-down/isometric games like this one, but I wanted to find an example that would contrast both styles. First person examples with both HUD and non-HUD chrome are harder to find, but old-school dungeon crawlers sometimes use this kind of mix too. Here the "Small Cave Troll" label, level, and health bar are HUD since they're overlaid on the world, while the rest of the GUI sits (mostly) outside the player's window to the world and isn't "heads-up" in this sense.

[image: Screenshot of The Nights & Candles]

Some games will also have floating windows or panels, like inventory management interfaces, that sit on top of the viewport. When these are mostly opaque, I'd generally consider them to be non-HUD GUI elements because they obscure a sizeable chunk of the game world in much the same way as the dashboard chrome examples.

Comment: If you want something first-person with a non-HUD interface, try original-flavor Doom: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/de/Doom_ingame_1.png

Comment: Would it be more correct to say that HUDs are a *part* of a GUI? Just to illustrate they're not quite synonymous.

Comment: Not necessarily more *correct*. We can say "all dogs are animals" without implying that "all animals are dogs" ;) The "is-a" relationship is not always [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation)

Comment: I would say that this usage of HUD does not match with the way that it has been used in games I have worked on.

Comment: @JackAidley I'm curious in what way. Both our answers say the defining feature of the HUD is that it's *overlaid* on the player's view of the game world, either fixed in screen space or positioned to follow the on-screen position of an object in the world. We both contrast this against UI that would require the player to look away from the world to read. Where do our definitions diverge?

Comment: @DMGregory: I would include the elements at the bottom of the screen in your Starcraft screenshot as HUD. In retrospect I should have explained that in my initial comment, my bad.

Comment: I've always thought the GUI exists as part of the games interface with the outside world - the description for the dials, life counter, score that you as a player can see.  The HUD on the other hand is the in universe display that your character can see - it's what's being displayed on the inside of your characters helmet - this includes any radar displays, bullets left in your gun, incoming messages from HQ.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook the term for interface elements that exist in-fiction / that the characters can see is "[diegetic interface](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DiegeticInterface)". This includes both literal heads-up displays a character might have projected inside their helmet or cockpit screen, and non-HUD interfaces like the instrument panel in the Steel Battalion screenshot at that link.

Comment: @DMGregory Wow - diegetic.  Had to look that one up. :)  Why call a spade a spade when you can call it a mobile soil conveyance device.  I'd still say a HUD though - the cockpit screen on the link would require your eyes to refocus when moving between the console and the view out the window.  I'd see a HUD as sitting over your view out of the window so the only part of the link screenshot would be the text on the window - 3.05 in the bottom right, NML in the bottom left and some kind of map in the middle?

Comment: So, "What would be described as GUI in this image and what as HUD?" in the OPs question?

Comment: This answer defines content overlaid on the player's view of the world as HUD, so all UI elements in that Overwatch screenshot are HUD according to this definition (and they're also graphical user interface, since this definition is not exclusive). That particular screen doesn't contain any user interface that sits outside of or substantially occludes the world viewport, unlike the contrasting examples in the answer above.

Comment: TL;DR: **all UI elements in that Overwatch screenshot are HUD**

Comment: "This answer defines content overlaid on the player's view of the world as HUD, so all UI elements in that Overwatch screenshot are HUD according to this definition" No, there are many elements that are not HUD. For instance, the arrows on the left, and the actual gun (as opposed to gun icon in the bottom right) are not HUD. If the force-field looking thing is actually in the game universe, that is also not HUD.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think the arrows, gun, and force-field looking thingy are elements of the virtual world, not part of a HUD *or* of the GUI. Well, that is unless you were trying to say that the ground and sky and ALL elements of the 3D world are also UI elements, since the player "interacts" with them by playing the game.  That would make for an interesting semantic debate, but I don't think that's what you were saying.  Also, how has the word "subset" not appeared in this thread??

Comment: "he label next to a control on a form is still part of the GUI" as an aside, outside of gamedev, form based UI is often not considered GUI. GUI has affordances for direct manipulation - you can drag to move or resize, click on a button, rather than just filling out a form, which (apart from looking prettier) doesn't behave differently to what it did on a mainframe text terminal, it's not intrinsically graphical.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this answer is that, in software, GUI is usually the opposite of a *command line* interface (abbreviated CLI), which HUDs are obviously not. Not that purely textual interfaces that aren't exactly the typical command/result REPL type interface, e.g. Rogue's ASCII art or the emacs editor with its keystrokes, are typically considered more closely related to the family of command line interfaces and not considered GUIs.

Comment: I have always thought of HUDs as containers for GUIs whenever you are inside a game during gameplay and when you are in the start menu or a load screen you only see GUIs because there's is no need of HUDs due to the lack of a secondary reality.

Answer (score 26):

**Interactivity**.

A HUD is not interactive: it displays information only, it cannot be clicked, dragged, closed, etc.

A GUI in a game is like any other UI: it is interactive. It has menus, buttons, scrollbars and other UI elements.

The term Head Up Display refers to fighter jets: displaying information on a canopy means that the pilot does not need to look down at the gauges and indicators on the dashboard.

Comment: A GUI implies user interaction, but but doesn't require it.  HUD's typically aren't interactive, but that's not to say they can't.  I would think an interactive HUD would get in the way of gameplay, though.  And I've opened/closed HUD's using a key-combo, not the "typical Windows" buttons.  Some HUDs were on the pilots helmet visor, and HUDs are now found on passenger vehicles, to expand on where they can be found.

Comment: @computercarguy - If your HUD is interactive, then it just became a GUI. One is a *D*isplay; the other, an *I*nterface.

Comment: If I have a bullet counter in my HUD that decreases when I pull the trigger, is that not interaction? ;)

Comment: I'm surprised how many people here don't seem to consider one-way communication to be interaction.  I've always considered it so.  The sender acts to provide information over some channel, and the receiver acts to internalize the information and allow it to change their state.  Hence both parties are involved in an action involving each other.  Interaction.

Comment: @DMGregory: No, it's not. You did not press the "decrease bullet by one" button in your HUD. You pressed the trigger, and the HUD continued to display the same information as before. The *value* may change, but the *information* is the same.

Comment: It is quite common in games for HUD elements to be interactive, so I cannot agree with this answer. It might have some kind of technical correctness but it does not match with how the terms are actually used.

Comment: Yes, lots of games have interactive HUDs... maybe not directly through mouse clicks but by keyboard controls, different indicators light up, etc.

Comment: @bcrist I'm not surprised how many people consider "one-way" anything to be "inter" anything because by definition, something "inter" anything is two way. It's the defining difference between "act" and "interact."

Comment: Arguably, a HUD is interactive if user input causes a change. Ammo counters, health counters, a compass. These can all change in response to use input.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, the "inter-" prefix can mean a reciprocal relationship but it doesn't need to be.  The important part is that it's a relationship between two or more independent entities, not that the relationship is symmetric.

Comment: @bcrist No, it actually does need to be. Just because something is responsive does n't mean it's interactive. Words mean something.

Answer (score 6):

> Is a HUD part of the GUI and just displaying information?

Yes. Head Up Display (as the name suggests) is just to display information while you are in-game. However in some scenarios HUD may be intractable.
For example in a mobile based game there are on screen buttons to perform different actions while you are **in-game**.

Answer (score 5):

GUI and HUD are **inexact terms**, meaning people will know what they mean, *unless they require specifics*. The specific meanings attached to the terms depend on subculture, company, the current project, or the team within that project you're working on. Proof: divergent answers on this very question.

The term HUD in terms of graphics often reminds of Terminator and Robocop. Beyond this, its meaning in games is **not standardized** and if you want to use the term to refer to specifics, you need to explain your use of the term first:

[image: Robocop][image: Terminator]

The GUI is *usually* everything you see on screen. It can in- or exclude some things that are not part of the main window, such as system tray menus, application icons, etc. It can include the input handling, but doesn't have to.  GUI is sometimes incorrectly used to refer to visual + audio. The better term in these cases would be UI, but sometimes GUI is used.

Comment: I noticed this too, just before scrolling to your answer. I summarized it as a point to the OP to add the definition of HUD they're looking for. A little surprised so many answers came in with one definition or another and didn't notice this schism ;)

Answer (score 3):

The gui in a game is pretty much everything gets displayed on the screen except for the game world,such as the player, the gun, the game world etc.. the hud is everything used to show information like the players health, the bullets count etc

Answer (score 3):

The term HUD comes from fighter planes where information to be relayed to the pilot is projected onto the cockpit screen rather than displayed on instruments within the cockpit. The point being that the pilot does not need to look away from the world outside to gather relevant information. It is used by analogy in computer games so it does not have a clear, well-defined, usage.

Typically, the HUD is the part of the user interface that is (a) is not moved with the gameworld (excepting elements that are positioned relative to in-game objects, e.g. health or name labels) and (b) is overlayed onto the game world, so that it can be obscured only by other HUD elements. In most cases the HUD is 2D, but some FPSs (in particular) now have 3D HUD elements.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI is what the user *interacts* with.
The HUD is what the game is *displaying* to the player.

I'd say everything in the image is the HUD. If you open the menu, that would be
the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I look at it this way: an HUD displays ongoing information to the user during the game, while a GUI appears in response to certain events and allows the user to *control* some aspect of the game. Usually the user cannot interact with other parts of the game while the GUI is open.

So for example in Minecraft, the health bar and hotbar at the bottom is an HUD, providing information about the player's status at all times. The player's inventory and the inventories for interacting with chests, furnaces, etc. are GUIs that the player opens by pressing a key or right-clicking on the blocks in the world. While the GUIs are open, the player cannot perform other actions or even clearly see what else is happening in the game.

I'd also apply the term "GUI" in game design to menus for controlling the game itself, such as the menus to exit the game or change settings that typically appear when the user presses the escape key. Although these aren't part of the gameplay; they're more part of the surrounding application.

Answer (score 0):

### GUI is a poor term to use in game dev

Classically, GUI meant any visual element that either provided information to the user or could be interacted with in some way.

In (most) games, that means EVERYTHING on the screen falls under this classic description of GUI.

The term HUD exists explicitly to supersede this now useless term (in this field). It displays information on top of the game layer that the player needs to make informed decisions.

Comment: In practice, the term GUI is still used a lot in games - see for instance the [tag:gui] tag on this exchange, with over 400 questions. And as pointed out in other answers, we use a lot of user interface elements in games that are *not* HUD too,  including menus, toolbars, windows, so I wouldn't say that HUD completely supersedes its use.

Comment: So FTL's entire gameplay, nearly every games inventory system, main menus, none of that is GUI, they're only HUDs? I entirely disagree with this, and it's far to particularly fit to your opinion, rather than providing a useful answer to the question.

Comment: I think Weckar has a point though.  Classically, the GUI is the Graphics, in contrast to old dungeon crawlers that were text based. This also fits for nearly every non-game program (TextUI vs GUI).  In modern games, generally everything is produced by graphics.

Comment: Why was this at the very bottom with a -1? Every other answer seems incorrect. Maybe you should show examples of TUI (Text User Interface) and CLI (Command Line Interface) games with screenshots for comparison and explain the differences of the interface types. For example, nethack is a TUI game, battlestar from bsd in a CLI game. That's where the GUI term is useful.

Comment: @DMGregory That tag description is horrible...